# Android DexClassLoader how to use for class with parameters and arguments

Tags: java, android

I want to load external class from .jar file. It works fine.

Load class with DexClassLoader :

```
DexClassLoader classLoader = new DexClassLoader(
                libFile.getAbsolutePath(), 
                tmpDir.getAbsolutePath(), 
                null, 
                ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
        Class<?> customFileClass = null; // extends File class
        try {
            customFileClass = (Class<?>) classLoader.loadClass("test.MyClass");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        }
```

i know, how i can use functions defined inside of the class, but how i can use it like:

```
File f = new File("/dir/File.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

After hours of searches and tests, i have found the solution.

1. Define new DexClassLoader:

   ```
   // .jar file must be Dexted. I know 2 ways to do that:
   // 1. Through console: dx  --dex --output="output.jar" "input.jar"
   // 2. You can import dx.jar from Android-Sdk/build-tools/xx.x.x/lib/dx.jar in your app and convert .jar file with command: 
   // String[] command = new String[] {"--dex", "--output="output.jar", "input.jar"};
   // com.android.dx.command.Main.main(command);
   DexClassLoader classLoader = new DexClassLoader(
   "absolutePathToJarFile", 
   "absolutePathToTmpDir", 
   null, 
   DexClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
   ```
2. Define Class to be loaded:

   ```
   Class<?> myClass = null;
   myClass = classLoader.loadClass("my.test.app.neededClass");
   ```
3. If the Class needs Arguments, like `new myClass("arg1", "arg2");`, we need to create new Arguments Class:

   ```
   Class<?>[] args = new Class[1]; // 1 is the number of Arguments
   args[0] = String.class; // First Argument of Type "String"
   ```
4. To associate Arguments with the Class, we define new Constructor:

   ```
   Constructor<?> constructor = null;
   try {
       constructor = myClass.getDeclaredConstructor(args);
   } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   }
   Object neededClass = null;
   neededClass = constructor.newInstance("First String Argument");`
   ```
5. Now we can extract known Functions defined inside of neededClass to Methods, like:

   ```
   Method exists = null;
   exists = myClass.getMethod("exists"); // exists() is the defined boolean Function inside of neededClass.
   exists.setAccessible(true);         
   if((boolean) exists.invoke(neededClass)){
       // do if true
   } else {
       // do if false
   }
   ```

The Problem with Classes like `File` is, we need to invoke Method inside of `AsyncTask`. If we try to invoke Method outside of `AsyncTask`, defined Functions of the Class like `File.exists()` will be not invoked and we get Error `InvocationTargetException`.